# Learning to query UniData

Tags: database, unidata, u2, multivalue-database

We have an IBM UniData server. I just installed UniObject .net. It looks like you just issue unidata queries through the .net classes.

Where can I learn the query language/syntax and to work with UniData in general? What books, sites, or videos do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource is going to be Rocket Software's [UniData library](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/pubs/library/72unidata/).

Rocket recently acquired the U2 family of products, which includes UniData and UniVerse, from IBM.  They've got a pretty extensive catalog of documentation for UniData.  You might want to check out the "[Using UniQuery](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/epubs/pdf/29921170.pdf)" document, which discusses the UniQuery in particular.

Unfortunately, you won't find many books, screencasts, or programming communities devoted to UniData because it's pretty esoteric.  If you run into anything specific that you've got questions on, it can't hurt to post here using the UniData tag and I'll do my best.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of information on the U2UG (U2 User Group).  There is a learner pack:

http://212.241.202.162/cms/cmsview.wsp?id=learner_pack

This will help.

International Spectrum has webinars that cover the Query language, and can put in touch with a trainer if you are interested:

http://www.intl-spectrum.com/

Answer (score 1):

Besides the [Using UniQuery](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/epubs/pdf/29921170.pdf) document, the [UniQuery Commands Reference](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/epubs/pdf/29921160.pdf) is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

The general structure of the query is

verb table filter order display

SORT CUSTOMER IF HATSIZE = "7" BY SHOESIZE NAME CITY STATE ZIP

Where
verb  = SORT
table = CUSTOMER
filter = IF HATSIZE = "7" (you can have multiple filters
order = BY SHOESIZE (you can have multiple order elements)
display = ID NAME CITY STATE ZIP (ID isn't on the list, but it is implied)

For this to work, the TABLE (also called a FILE) named CUSTOMER has to exist.
CUSTOMER must have a dictionary (schema/view repository) which defines HATSIZE SHOESIZE NAME CITY STATE and ZIP.

A more coherent example:

SORT CUSTOMER IF ORDER.LIMIT > "12,000.00" AND WITHOUT STATUS "INACTIVE" BY-DSND ORDER.LIMIT BY ZIP ORDER.LIMIT ZIP NAME STATUS

Which would select CUSTOMERs with $12K or more ORDER.LIMIT who are not INACTIVE and sort them form biggest limit to least... you get the idea.